# CGMatter Facial motion capture tutorial - script error

Tags: animation, scripting, bones, error, tracking

I am working on the facial animation following the cgmatters tutorial: https://youtu.be/uNK8S19OSmA

Everything works fine except script from the end of the video. I have more than 200 trackers so im getting python error. Code looks like this:

```
for value in range(1,iter):
if value == 1:
bonename = “Bone”
elif value > 1 and value < 11:
bonename = “Bone.00” + str(value-1)
elif value >= 11 and value < 100:
bonename = “Bone.0” + str(value-1)
elif value >= 100:
bonename = “Bone.” + str(value-1)
bone = bpy.data.objects[‘Armature’].data.bones.get(bonename)
bpy.data.objects[‘Armature’].data.bones[bonename].name = ‘Bone’ + str(value)
```

It should rename my 215 bones but im getting messege:

`"line 63, in
KeyError: ‘bpy_prop_collection[key]: key “Bone.99” not found’

full script:

```
#CGMatter Face Mocap Script
import bpy

iter = 1

#rename trackers
FaceTrackers = bpy.data.collections.new('FaceTrackers')
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(FaceTrackers)
for trackers in bpy.data.objects:
   if trackers.type != 'EMPTY':
       continue
   else:
       iter = iter + 1
       FaceTrackers.objects.link(trackers)
if FaceTrackers:
    for i, o in enumerate(FaceTrackers.objects):
        o.name = "Tracker%d" % (i+1) 

#face mesh setup
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.name = "Head"
    obj.data.name = "Head"
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()

#trackers with depth
for value in range(1,iter):
    selectname = "Tracker" + str(value)
    ob = bpy.data.objects[selectname]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    bpy.context.object.constraints["Follow Track"].depth_object = bpy.data.objects["Head"]

#add armatures to trackers
for value in range(1,iter):
    selectname = "Tracker" + str(value)
    ob = bpy.data.objects[selectname]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    bpy.ops.object.armature_add(enter_editmode=False, location=ob.matrix_world.translation)

#select armatures
for bones in bpy.data.objects:
   if bones.type != 'ARMATURE':
       continue
   else:
       bones.select_set(state=True)    

#join armatures in correct order
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
bpy.ops.object.join()
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()    

#rename bones in armature
for value in range(1,iter):
    if value == 1:
        bonename = "Bone"
    elif value > 1 and value < 11:
        bonename = "Bone.00" + str(value-1)
    elif value >= 11 and value < 100:
        bonename = "Bone.0" + str(value-1)
    elif value >= 100:
        bonename = "Bone." + str(value-1)       
    bone = bpy.data.objects['Armature'].data.bones.get(bonename)
    bpy.data.objects['Armature'].data.bones[bonename].name = 'Bone' + str(value)

#parent face to bones
bpy.data.objects['Head'].select_set(True)
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='ARMATURE_AUTO')

#parent bones to trackers
bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
for value in range(1,iter):
    trackname = "Tracker" + str(value)
    bonename = "Bone" + str(value)
    bone = bpy.data.objects['Armature'].data.bones.get(bonename)
    bpy.data.objects['Armature'].data.bones.active = bone
    bpy.ops.pose.constraint_add(type='COPY_LOCATION')
    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[bonename].constraints["Copy Location"].use_z = False
    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[bonename].constraints["Copy Location"].target = bpy.data.objects[trackname]
    bone.select = False
`
```

I have also attached blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17lD4iZkZZH5eJbxSrWrC3aMeLDhYtLkK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. Please post the full script and *ideally* your blend. Looks like your bones are not named properly. Also at a first glance: the script from the tutorial: https://youtu.be/uNK8S19OSmA?t=1413 looks pretty bad, a lot of data is hardcoded for whatever reason... which can cause the error as well.

Comment: hi! thanks! i have edited the post

Comment: A quick and dirty fix: https://pasteall.org/L38c/raw Please test and let us know whether it works or not. I will revise the script if I have the time, doesn't look like python rather bad javascript code to me.